# Call REST API with authentication using Python

Tags: python, rest

I'm a beginner and learning Python. I wanted to write a python code to "call an REST API". Can you please guide me the steps to call an Rest API?

Also I've curl command which I wanted to write it in python code.

curl -u username:password -X GET 'http://google.com:8070/api/v2/organizations'

It would much helpful if anyone can help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best option for you is possibly using `requests` package. 
install it with `pip install requests`.
An exapmple taken from their website is:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

For further info check its [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score -2):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get("http://google.com:8070/api/v2/organizations",auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

you should really read some docs and write some code... these things become really obvious with some very quick googling (ie "python http authentication request")

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/